# Defining/using a class built from preset components (in C++)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to a design for a system where the user can define their own class as an aggregate of a number of predefined components, and then have this class work with algorithms which I provide. I am trying to do this with compile time and/or template based approaches rather than run time polymorphism or virtual functions as performance is important in this case.

For example, consider that I have a number of components which can be used to build a 3D vertex. I will define these components as Position, Normal, Color, etc, and then the user will be able (via multiple inheritance, composition, or what?) to define a vertex such as PositionAndColorVertex which has only position and color but no normal . Now, I provide a function which does some processing on a vector of one million these vertices:

```
template<typename UsersVertexType>
void myProvidedAlgorithm(std::vector<UsersVertexType> input)
{
    if(vertex has a position)
        //do stuff with position
    if(vertex has a normal)
        //do stuff with normal
    if(vertex has a color)
        //do stuff with color
}
```

Now, I don't know what UsersVertexType will look like but it will be built from my components. My functions needs to do something with each of the components but only if they exist. What is an elegant and fast (compile time) way of expressing this?

Of course, I could define a base class for each type, make the user inherit from the desired base classes, and then use dynamic_cast to check which components are implemented, but this is exactly the sort of runtime approach I would like to avoid. Perhaps I can check this inheritance relationship at compile time (the compiler should know what UsersVertexType actually is, right?).

Perhaps my components should be expressed using C++ concepts or policies? I've also seen talk of mixins but not sure these are useful. Should the users class use multiple inheritance or composition? Maybe I should somehow get a set of flags into the users class, indicating what it contains? How would you design this system?

Thanks for any insight!

**Note:** There are similarities to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601798/advantages-of-type-traits-vs-static-members), but here I am taking a step back and looking for higher level design options/alternatives.

Comment: reinventing Boost Graph Library?

Comment: Setting the flags on user classes sounds like a good idea. A single extra variable with OR checks on flags for each element or better yet, checking the number directly if you are checking for a combination of flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traits and template specializations.

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename V> struct traits; // Primary template.
```

Then define a version for your vertices with positional component, and one for vertices without:

```
template <typename Vertex, bool has_position=traits<Vertex>::has_position> 
struct some_position_op;

template <typename Vertex> struct some_position_op<Vertex,false> {
    void operator() () { std::cout << "has no position.\n"; }
};

template <typename Vertex> struct some_position_op<Vertex,true> {
    void operator() () { std::cout << "has position.\n"; }
};
```

Finally, for each vertex-type you define, implement a traits class:

```
struct MyVertexWithPosition {};
template <> 
struct traits<MyVertexWithPosition> {
    static constexpr bool has_position = true;
};


struct MyVertexWithoutPosition {};
template <> 
struct traits<MyVertexWithoutPosition> {
    static constexpr bool has_position = false;
};
```

... and have fun:

```
template <typename Vertex>
void shade (Vertex const &vtx) {
    some_position_op<Vertex>() ();
}

int main () {
    shade (MyVertexWithPosition());
    shade (MyVertexWithoutPosition());
}
```

You could also specialize function templates, but would have to sacrifice some of the readability of your `shade` function.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think I can use something like this. sehe's answer is also correct in the use of traits but I'll accept this one for being a more complete example.

Answer (score 4):

The usual pattern is using `type_traits`, and/or the use freestanding function templates that can be specialized for the UserVertexType.

Add a bit of SFINAE overload selection magic and voila: you have invented template meta-programming and Boost Graph Library.

Small idea sample:

```
template <typename VertexType>
struct vertex_traits // default vertex_traits:
{
    typename unused_tag position_type;
    enum { 
        hasNormal = 0 // treat as 'boolean'
        hasColor = 0 
    }; 
};

template <typename V> vertex_traits<V>::position_type& position(V&);
```

The idea is, that by making the generic stuff be defined *outside* the class you don't impose any unnecessary restrictions on the user's choice of vertex type (they could just use std::pair, they might just pass a third party type and decorate it for use with your graph library etc.)

Google:  "How Non-Member Functions Improve Encapsulation" (by Scott Meyer)

Comment: Ok, this is good information. As well as the BGL/Meyers links you provided, I've also come across [defining custom meshes in OpenMesh](http://openmesh.org/Documentation/OpenMesh-2.0-Documentation/mesh_type.html) which also takes a traits based approach. I will look at these further.